# alfa AWUS036AC USB WIFI adapter

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, usb, 14.10

I am running Xubuntu 14.10 amd64. I have the latest USB adapter from alfa, model AWUS036AC. I downloaded linux drivers for it, they are not packaged to easily install. I do not know how to install the drivers. I unarchived the .tgz file, and it has some folders and files, one file is named makefile. I think my problem is just a lack of knowledge about linux, not that the driver doesn't work. At this point I don't even know what dir the drivers go in. The lsusb command shows the device "Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.", it's just not showing up as a usable network adapter, most likely because it's pretty new. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this, you already finished step 1 and 2, the directory name in step 3 will be "rtl8812au_linux-master" for you.

Comment: @P.-H.Lin Your suggested duplicate is for an RTL8187 chipset, not 8812au.

Comment: @chili555 The instructions there provides enough information for doing this from scratch, my 2 cents.

Comment: @P.-H.Lin You haven't said where he gets rtl8812au_linux-master.

Comment: @chili555 if you did download the driver from the alfa website, you will see that directory, he said he did unarchived it, so he will know that.

Comment: Will he? "I think my problem is just a lack of knowledge about linux..." My last word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install TP-LINK Archer T4U driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver)

Answer (score 8):

With a working temporary internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8812au
```

It 'makes' with a couple of possibly harmless warnings but no errors on my system.

After Update Manager installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, and after the required reboot, recompile:

```
cd ~/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8812au
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic

Comment: @Prinsig Please start your own new question and tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Prinsig An earlier version of this answer gave the module name without the `rtl` prefix. I believe the correct command is `sudo modprobe rtl8812au`. Credit goes to [Alexey Agapov](https://askubuntu.com/a/871735/22949) for [pointing this out](https://askubuntu.com/a/871735). I've tested both module names to verify that `rtl8812au` is the one that works, and edited this post accordingly. (That should fix your "Module 8812au not found" problem, since the error message you got is the expected message when giving `modprobe` the name of a module that is not installed.)

Comment: I made a silly mistake by thinking that RTL (rtl8812au) was "RTI". Silly me. Might help someone else.