# Trouble With USB Wireless NIC BCM5754

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, usb, broadcom

I've done some research. It seems that many people struggled with Broadcom USB NIC's several years ago, but now I don't see a lot of topics asking for help. It's definitely not a "plug and play" success for me; the computer recognizes that it's a D-Link USB device.

However, it doesn't show up in the network connections dialogue, and I get this message when I run lsusb :

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2001:3315 D-Link Corp.
```

I've had a really hard time understanding what I'm even looking for. The Broadcom website references a "one size fits all" driver, tg3, and I'm not quite sure how or where to d/l that from - it seems like it should already be included with the default linux kernel. I tried using b43 fwcutter with very little success. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your device ID **2001:3315** D-Link Corp. works with the driver 8812au. I wrote a tutorial about this a few days ago here: [alfa AWUS036AC USB WIFI adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573737/alfa-awus036ac-usb-wifi-adapter/573741#573741)

Please reply if you get stuck and I'll be very happy to help.